# Simple Select statement does not return any result

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have one database table name `test123` and having column `name`. And it contains the data like `'nir,kal,man'` Now, when i am querying the table with select statement as per below :

```
select * from test123 where name = 'nir,kal,man';
```

But this will not return any result...Why this happened.? How i have to write query so that will return the result?
I am using Sql server 2008.

Thanks...!

Comment: Is `nir,kal,man` a single name, or three different names `nir`,`kal`,`man`?!!! I think may be you are missing `SPACE` somewhere. check the query with `LIKE` operator..

Answer (score 5):

`=` operator returns exact match, so if your cell contain data "like" that you need to use `LIKE` operator:

```
select * from test123 where name like '%nir,kal,man%'
```

where `%` will be replaced with any set of characters.

Also check that you're targeting correct database by using full name

```
select * from yourdb.dbo.test123 where....
```

Answer (score 3):

if Nir is in first row Kal in 2nd row and man is in 3rd row then you should write query like this

```
select * from test123 where name in ('nir','kal','man')
```

Comment: Just change `select * from test123 where name = ('nir','kal','man')` to `select * from test123 where name IN ('nir','kal','man')` :-)